# Which account is used to authenticate ASP.net to SQL when using a trusted connection?

Tags: sql, asp.net, vb.net, active-directory

I'm just in the process of trying to properly configure asp.net 4.5 on our IIS servers.

I have been able to navigate and launch an ASPX page that contains no data conenctions sucessfully so I know that the application pool authentication to the local directories is working as it should.

Now though I have a seperate SQL server that is connected to the domain and have a connection string stored in the code that connects the ASPX page to the server using a trusted connection. When running in visual studio debug mode, the connection works fine - but at that point I assume it is using my login credentials.

My question is, when a user calls the aspx page via the browser when hosted on the new IIS7 server, which account is used to call the SQL server when using a trusted connection? - Is it the end users or is it a local account from the IIS server?

When I call a page with data connections embedded I get the error: Login failed for user ADMIN\PCNAME$ ... which is an indication that this is the account that it is using. However this account doesn't exist on the domain that I'm aware of. - Or does it ?!

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will use the account that ASP.NET is running under, as you've worked out. What you usually should do is create a Domain Account (with the right privileges) and run your ASP.NET AppPool under that account. Then a Trusted Connection will use that account for connecting to the database, and as long as you've given it access (which as a Domain Account you can do) it should all work.

Added:

After some back and forth on comments, lets go back to the start: set the new AppPool to run with the domain users account, and recycle the AppPoolo. What is it that says the password is wrong? If it's IIS trying to start the AppPool, then it is extremeny likely that the Password you gave the AppPool IS wrong, or else that the password is set to change on first logon.
If its not IIS, but opening a Database connection, are you sure that the database allows this Domain Account access to the database and the tables within it it will need? What roles have you assigned to this account? Also, what SQL statement is it trying to execute (if it's got far enough to try and execute a statement at all)?

I suggest you put any response in you original question - comments get to be a drag if there are too many of them.

Comment: Hi, thanks that makes sense. I've tried doing two things since then - firstly changing the application pool so that it uses specific credntials of a service account we had configured with access to teh SQL server, and also using my credentials which also has access. I don't seem to  be able to apply the change though and each time I get an error to say that the password is invalid as per:

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/421658/iis-7-using-domain-account-for-application-pool-identity-invalid-password However unfortunately there is no solution to that thread! ... have you see nthis issue before?

Comment: Are you using Impersonation at all? Check the web.config file.

Comment: Following advice from here: http://forums.iis.net/t/1180450.aspx I tried adding my credntials to the local administrator group - this now allows the database page to load correctly on the local host, however if I try to connect to it from another machine then I get a "internet explorer cannot display the page" error. I assume this is because the anon authentication is still set to use the app pool account, so I changed this to my credentials also... but still it won't load. As far as I can see - Impersonation isn't used. - Feels like I'm close!

Comment: This is really odd too: The first webesite (Default) is accessable via the IP address from a remote PC. If I put  10.200.38.123:8080 (address of the second website) - it doesn't work. Looking at the anon auth settings, the first uses ISUR and the second uses the application pool identity (changed back from my credentials), ... switching this to use ISUR however means that the page stops working on the local host too. Baffled!

Comment: Resolved this by adding a firewall exception for inbound port 8080.